# OpenLayers 6.8 : How to get Geojson Vector coordinates?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I have a basic map with openlayers 6.8.
I display markers from geojson.

Example of a geojson :

```
const geoMoscow = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: './assets/moscow.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    visible: true,
    title: 'geojson',
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: fillStyle,
        stroke: strokeStyle,
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: [245, 49, 5, 1]
            }),
            radius: 10,
        }),
    })
})
```

I want to get this geojson coordinates for further use.
I have been reading many code examples that uses geojson.getSource().getFeatures() that allows to acces the getCoordinates() method from each feature.

Unfortunetly geoMoscow.getSource().getFeatures() gives an empty array.

I am obviously missing something there about openlayers logic.
It seems totally doable because my geojson contains a feature object with the coordinates in it but I am unable to access it.

**TLDR : How to access informations like coordinates from this geojson Vector.**

Answer (score 2):

You must wait until the source is loaded and parsed

```
geoMoscow.getSource().on('featuresloadend', function(){
  console.log(geoMoscow.getSource().getFeatures());
});
```

The source  will not load until it is added to a map.

Comment: It works perfectly. 
I was sure I was missing something like that but wrapping my code in :
window.onload = init;
function init() {}
isn't supposed to avoid this issue ?

Comment: The window.onload event fires after all the script tags and dom has loaded that were initially in your html. Your geojson only starts loading after the script is executed and the VectorSource is constructed.